# Options to prevent direct downloads

Tags: php, nginx, download, mirror

I want to create a mirroring site for Android ROMs and of course I don't want users to link files directly. There are many options that come to mind.

1) control the referral, this can be done via PHP or Web Server but it's a poor approach since this can be easily changed and not all browser work the same way.

2) authenticate users with some short-session and checks and then let the users download. This could work but I'll eventually have to give away a direct link on the webserver and nobody stops user for sharing this direct link destroying the authentication protection.

3) use PHP with readfile() or similar: this is definitely the most secure way cause users must go through the website but that would require many PHP processes to handle all the requests at once (one process per user) and considering files could take minutes to download I would need many GBs of RAM. Not very cheap or resources friendly.

4) move files temporally to a location and let the user download for a limited amount of time. This require huge amount of space and could cause I/O slowdowns. Also not using readfile() I have no way of knowing if the file has been downloaded 100% to free space.

There's nothing else I can think of, is there another way to do it that doesn't require huge RAM or HDD space but just some smart scripting?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check the nginx [secure link module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSecureLinkModule), will allow people to download directly from nginx (no php involved in the downloading process), but also disallow direct linking to files, and you can have an expiry time/date.